# Finding 5 numbers in binary array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

[Math side](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580855/generating-binary-array)

I have this task where I need to get 5 numbers in binary array, but i cant think of way to generate it. The building process is:

Starts Width 10 then adds same number but 1 and 0 are switched places like this

> 10
>
> 10 + 01
>
> 1001 + 0110
>
> 10010110 + 01101001
>
> 1001011001101001 + 0110100110010110
>
> ...

I can't figure out way to find n, n+1, n+2, n+3 and n+4 if I have only n<=2*10^9

**REMEMBER THIS ISN'T SCHOOL TASK** it's task from old Olympiad witch I'm doing to understand tasks concept and learning for next one

> Symbol array 1001011001101001... makes so - first is written 1 then last part of array writes at the end of existing one only changing 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 like this 1 → 10 → 1001 → 10010110 → ...
>
> Task: Write programm, that any given integer n in this array finds n, n+1, n+2, n+3 and n+ 4 symbol if n <= 2*10^9!

Comment: Step 1: Figure out the math. Step 2: Translate the math into program. Which step are you in?

Comment: If you are in first step, I recommend asking the question in the sister website http://math.stackexchange.com. It may be able to attract more and better attention over there. Also, the question may be considered a math question rather than programming, and thus may be considered off-topic in StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok i asked a question there, but if we imagine that i have algorithm? how could i make progamm to get those numbers?

Answer (score 1):

### [explanation is here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580855/generating-binary-array/1581072#1581072)

### code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <bitset>
 #include <array>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>


void finddigit(int n)
{   
    const int a[]={1,4,6,7,10,11,13,16};
    int b[]={2,3,5,8,9,12,14,15};
    std::vector<int> t ;
    std::vector<int>::iterator found;
    int floored=(int)(floor((double)n/8));
    int residue=n-8*floored;

    if(residue==0) 
        residue=n-(--floored)*8; 

    std::string bin = std::bitset<8>(floored).to_string();

    if (std::count(bin.begin(), bin.end(), '1')%2==0) 
        t.assign(a,a+8);
    else t.assign(b,b+8);
        found=std::find(std::begin(t), std::end(t), residue);

    if (found != t.end()) 
        std::cout << "1";
    else 
        std::cout << "0";

}
```

### usage

```
void main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    for (int i=1;i<65;i++)
        finddigit(i);
}
```

### Result

```
1001011001101001011010011001011001101001100101101001011001101001
```

- **Note:** excuse me for any maladjustment that shows in the body of my answer, I would like to improve.

Answer (score 0):

```
(2 << 2) & (~2) // 1000 + 01 = 1001 = 9
(9 << 4) & (~9) // 10010000 + 0110 = 10010110 
// an so on ..
```

We can notice here is the offstet is forever doubled.
2, 4, 8

`~` means negation 
`&` means and
`<<` means make offset to the left
So, it is all what we need it is make that bit operations with our array

You can find there a function for make bit operations between two arrays

```
void and(void *result, const void *first, const void *second, size_t  lengthInBytes) {
 char *_result = (char*)result;
 char *_second = (char*)second;
 char *_first = (char*)first;
 for (size_t i = 0; i < lengthInBytes; i++) {
    _result[i] = _first[i] & _second[i]; // here can be any bit operation
 }
}
```